# How do I configure and execute BatchStatement in Cassandra correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, nosql, datastax-python-driver

In my **Python** (*3.8*) application, I make a request to the **Cassandra** database via [DataStax Python Driver 3.24](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/).

I have several CQL operations that I am trying to execute with a single query via [BatchStatement](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/query/#cassandra.query.BatchStatement) according to the official documentation. Unfortunately, my code causes an error with the following content:

```
"errorMessage": "retry_policy should implement cassandra.policies.RetryPolicy"
"errorType": "ValueError"
```

As you can see from my code I set the value for the `reply_policy` attribute inside `BatchStatement`. Anyway my code raise error which you see above. What kind of value must be inside the `reply_policy` property? What is the reason for the current conflict?

**Code Snippet**:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, ExecutionProfile, EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.query import dict_factory
from cassandra.query import BatchStatement, SimpleStatement
from cassandra.policies import RetryPolicy


auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=db_username, password=db_password)
default_profile = ExecutionProfile(
   load_balancing_policy=DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(local_dc=db_local_dc),
   consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM,
   request_timeout=60,
   row_factory=dict_factory
)
cluster = Cluster(
   db_host,
   auth_provider=auth_provider,
   port=db_port,
   protocol_version=4,
   connect_timeout=60,
   idle_heartbeat_interval=0,
   execution_profiles={EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT: default_profile}
)
session = cluster.connect()

name_1, name_2, name_3  = "Bob", "Jack", "Alex"
age_1, age_2, age_3 = 25, 30, 18

cql_statement = "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)"

batch = BatchStatement(retry_policy=RetryPolicy)
batch.add(SimpleStatement(cql_statement, (name_1, age_1)))
batch.add(SimpleStatement(cql_statement, (name_2, age_2)))
batch.add(SimpleStatement(cql_statement, (name_3, age_3)))
session.execute(batch)
```

Comment: why do you need that batch? if you just want to re-insert entry, just do insert - it will overwrite existing data because in Cassandra everything is UPSERT... Also, why do you need retry policy? just leave it & the default one will be used

Comment: @AlexOtt hello! As I said in my post, I have several CQL operations that I am trying to execute with a single query. I understand that each of the requests can be executed separately. Suppose I need to do an insert of a set of data (CQL query is the same, arguments are different). I already tried to remove the `reply_policy` property, but the error remained the same. By default, it is set to `None`, if you look under the hood of `BatchStatement`.  Do you have any ideas, my friend?

Comment: batch of delete + insert on the same primary key is tricky, and may not behave how you think it should behave... Please expand in the post what do you want to achieve, not how do you want to achieve.  Why you need to have delete + insert combination in the first place. also, adding the schema of the table will help

Comment: I understand. Here in the post is just an example. I actually need to perform an `INSERT` operation with different parameters only. I updated the post. Can you please check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the error.

I removed the `retry_policy` property from the `BatchStatement`. Then my mistake was that I put CQL arguments inside `SimpleStatement`.

Here is working example code snippet:

```
...
batch = BatchStatement(batch_type=BatchType.UNLOGGED)
batch.add(SimpleStatement(cql_statement), (name_1, age_1))
batch.add(SimpleStatement(cql_statement), (name_2, age_2))
batch.add(SimpleStatement(cql_statement), (name_3, age_3))
session.execute(batch)
```

**EDITED:**

As a result, I abandoned `BatchStatement` after comments left at the bottom of this post. I beg you to pay attention to them! CQL batches are not the same as RBDMS batches. CQL batches are not an optimization but for achieving atomic updates of a denormalized record across multiple tables.

Comment: please don't do it this way - the batches in Cassandra aren't optimization for writing. Really you will make your inserts slower. Use prepared statements instead + execute_async - google for bad & good use of the batches in Cassandra

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Apparently, you say this from a personally painful experience. But shouldn't `BatchStatement` work faster than executing individual queries? Imagine you need to record 100,000 records. Brute force will take a long time. Isn't it?

Comment: No. It won’t be faster because all load will be put onto coordinator node that will dispatch queries to nodes holding data, instead of driver sending these queries directly to that nodes. The fastest way to put a lot of data is to use prepared queries and execute_async... or use external tool like DSBulk

Comment: In recommend to grab free Cassandra book from DataStax...

Comment: Alex is correct. CQL batches are not the same as RBDMS batches. CQL batches are not an optimisation but for achieving atomic updates of a denormalised record across multiple tables. If it helps, I've explained them in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/articles/2744/. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez thank you for your comment and useful article. I will update my post with your comments for future visitors.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Hi, I know we shouldn't use CQL Batches, but I have a list of contaning data, each time I have to loop through the list then add data to db so it painfully slow without batch how can I achieve the speed like when I add single row of document?